# Instead of automatically updating db, generate sql script with fluent n-hibernate for production enviornment

Tags: sql, fluent-nhibernate, entity-framework-migrations, fluent-migrator

I've glanced over the different documentation, though have not found anything that addresses this. I'm looking at using fluentmigrator for future projects, though for staging/production practices have to do schema updates through a dba. I am allowed to do what I want for other environments such as testing, dev and local.

The purpose of the tool is entirely defeated if I have to write the scripts to do the changes anyway. However, it occurred to me, what if I didn't? So my question is this: Is it possible to have fluent migrate spit out a sql script to a file, instead of actually running the transaction?

In my experimentation I created a console app that uses the same DAL assembly as the main project, and leverages the migrator logic, so that whenever I run the console app, it updates the db from scratch, or from the nearest point depending on my choice.  We use TeamCity, so thought it could be cool to have it run the app and place the script ( as an artifact) in a folder as a step in the build process for our DBA in the environments updating the schema myself would be frowned upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FluentMigrator Command Line Runner](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Command-Line-Runner-Options) will generate SQL scripts, without applying the changes to the database, if you use:

- `--preview=true`
- `--output=true`
- `--outputFilename=output1.sql`

And, if you install the [FluentMigrator.Tools package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentMigrator.Tools/) in addition to the [FluentMigrator package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentMigrator/), you will have access to the Command Line Runner from the migration project's build output directory (`Migrate.exe`).

**Note:**
The generated scripts will contain inserts into the FluentMigrator version table.

Comment: I know these are old answers, but for future reference the documentation is now found here: https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/runners/runner-console.html#--preview--p-optional

Answer (score 0):

After reading [Command Line Runner Options](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Command-Line-Runner-Options) I'd use --verbose=true to output the sql script and --output to save it to a file. There seems to be no 'dry run' option however - you'll need to run the migration in some preproduction environment to obtain the script.

Give it a shot as I've admittedly never tried it.